# Creating a matrix with dates as columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've successfully created a tabular report in SSRS with my dates as rows. I'd like to make the dates as columns, and have my columns as rows. For example:

[image]

If I wanted to have the columns at the top, as rows (ie: ADP, DEATHS, INPATIENT HOSP, ALLERGY, etc.), how would I do this. My desired result would look similar to this:

```
                5/1/2013      5/2/2013     5/3/2013
ADP                  229           230          225
DEATHS                 0             0            0 
INPATIENT HOSP         0             0            0
ALLERGY                0             0            0
```

Would this be a matrix? One method I've tried is this, but the report isn't what I'm looking for:

[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is referred to as grouping. In this situation, you want two groups; one for the rows and one for the columns. To add a group, right-click on a cell in the table and select "Add Group". Then select "parent Group...". Select what you are grouping on such as by date. In the group properties you can specify other details such as sorting so that the dates are in order. The table should look something like this:

[image]

In the Data field you would use an aggregate such as Sum([adp]). When you view the report, the rows and columns will expand to fill in whatever data is in your dataset. This is the what makes reporting services so dynamic, the data can change, but the layout will still work. You may want to do some aditional research on how to set up a Matrix and customize grouping.